# calculation of mean curvature of surface of revolution?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, solid-of-revolution

The mean curvature of surface of revolution$$(x,y,z)=\big(r(\gamma) \cos(\theta),r(\gamma)\sin(\theta),z(\gamma)\big)$$ parameterized by $(\gamma,\theta)$
where
$$\dot{r}^2(\gamma)+\dot{z}^2(\gamma)=1$$

the
mean curvature $2 C=-\nabla.n$, where $n$ is the unit normal
$$n=\big(\dot{z}(\gamma)\cos(\theta),-\sin(\theta)\dot{z}(\gamma),\dot{r}(\gamma)\big),$$
the $\nabla=\partial/\partial x\hat{x}+\partial/\partial y\hat{y}+\partial/\partial z\hat{z}$.

How to change the $\nabla$ into the parameterized form $\gamma$, $\theta$, where $\gamma $ is the arc length of the curve?

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to find the principal curvatures (and hence the mean curvature) of a surface of revolution, but you can find the answer to your question about $\nabla$ in cylindrical coordinates [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).